# How can I make a program determine whether or not the input is an int in python?

Tags: python, while-loop

Good afternoon. I am trying to create a program to print descriptions of numbers. I'm in very basic python and am a bit stuck on this particular problem. Can anyone tell me how to have the program distinguish between numbers to continue the program, and the Q, Bye or carriage return to end the statement?

```
while True:

    N = eval(input("Enter an input: number to continue, Q, bye or carriage return to quit")

    if N == int

        N => 0 print("positive")

        else print("negative")
```

Comment: How should it react to a float?

Comment: Don't use `eval` unless you know what (evil things) it can do and only if there is no other way to reach the desired result.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `isinstance`:

```
if isinstance(N,int):
    #do something
```

Note that this sort of thing isn't recommended.  Especially when you're `eval` ing `raw_input`.  Here I would try something like:

```
#python2
try:
   N = int(raw_input("Enter integer:"))
except ValueError:
   print "Not an integer!"
```

or on python3:

```
#python2
try:
   N = int(input("Enter integer:"))
except ValueError:
   print("Not an integer!")
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a couple of different ways, depending on context:

```
try:
    i = int(a)
except ValueError:
    print >>sys.stderr, "Cannot be converted to integer"
```

or

```
if type(a) == type(1):
    print "Yep, that's an int"
```

Comment: Hard to disagree with you, Jakob. I have never loved the code around type-checking in Python.  I use these because they are clear and flow is natural.  isinstance from mgilson's answer may be slightly more graceful...